# Entity framework - 3 tables but only 2 are showing

Tags: entity-framework, primary-key, composite

I'm very new to EF, so please bear with me. I have 3 tables CustomerTable, ProductTable and OrdersTable.

The primary key of OrdersTable is the combination of CustomerTable and ProductTable primary keys which are CustomerID and ProductID, respectively.

OrdersTable has only 2 columns which are CustomerID and ProductID

In EF model, I've added all 3 tables but OrdersTable is not showing in edmx.

So one of my friend  told me the 3rd table OrdersTable is a "composite" table, because it both has the primary keys of both CustomerTable and ProductTable.

So my question now is, in simple terms, what makes a composite table with this given scenario?

I want to query/get all the contents of OrdersTable, but I was told I have to go through either CustomerTable or ProductTable first.

I did that using linq to sql, so CustomerTable can see ProductTable and vice versa, because of the navigation property, but I can't see OrdersTable.

What's the simple way of doing this, and why?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known defect of the Entity Framework, the composite keys will be converted to be a special association, not a table or model. A simple workaround solution is to create a new table with 3 fields. The first field (Id) set as the primary key, the other two fields are CustomerID and ProductID, and you have to maintain the integrity of the database by using your code not by the database system itself...